# how to download image from url and resize using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to download image from URL and resize automatically , any ideas ?

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
  Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
  ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
  ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim DirFile As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim FolderName As String
    Set ws = Sheet1

    FolderName = "C:\try"
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To LastRow
        For X = 19 To 27
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, X).Value <> "" Then
                strPath = FolderName & "\" & i - 3 & "-" & X - 18 & ".jpg"
                Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, Sheet1.Cells(i, X).Value, strPath, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next X
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "Resize" can mean different things - what specifically are you asking about?  Unless you're having a problem with your posted code that doesn't seem relevant to your actual question...

Comment: @TimWilliams 
I have successfully downloaded the image with the code above
but i want when downloading the image it is automatic with resizing.

Comment: Downloading and resizing are not related, so your question is about resizing, which means it would be useful to explain exactly what you mean by "resizing".  Start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+resize+image+file and try some of the approaches you find.  Post back with any specific problems you have with your code.